# Pointers to parallel apps using azure

Tags: azure, parallel-processing

If anyone knows resources/sample code to understand parallel processing on azure, please post the link. I want to analyse it for my personal project purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

- the new Daytona project from Microsoft - http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/cecba376-3d3f-4eaf-bf01-20983857c2b1/default.aspx
- Lokad's cloud platform - http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/
- Azure Grid - http://azuregrid.codeplex.com/
- Azure Affinity Grid - http://affinitygrid.codeplex.com/ (not so up to date)